# Sql query for monthly/yearly report

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, select

I have got a Sales table which has fields like

```
   upgrade[yes/no] 
   date upgraded[datetime] 
   user[username]
```

What I want to run a query and show upgrades monthly and yearly wise , for instance i want to generate a report like Jan 2012 [total upgrades made 30, user1 made 10 upgrades , user 2 made 15 upgrades, similarly
user 3 made 5 upgrades. Similarly I want to acheive that for yearly basis too.

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server

Comment: i was thinking of using GROUP BY Month/year(SomeDate) in select query , is that the right approach

Comment: Odd to see Mr A and Mr E interacting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SSRS`, you could generate multiple groupings fairly easily and display all of this information at-a-glance.

In a vanilla T-SQL query, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(s.[date upgraded]),
    s.[user],
    COUNT(*) AS [total upgrades]
FROM [Sales] s
WHERE s.[upgrade] = 'yes'
GROUP BY s.[user], YEAR(s.[date upgraded]) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY YEAR(s.[date upgraded]), s.[user]

SELECT
    MONTH(s.[date upgraded]),
    s.[user],
    COUNT(*) AS [total upgrades]
FROM [Sales] s
WHERE s.[upgrade] = 'yes'
GROUP BY s.[user], MONTH(s.[date upgraded]) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY MONTH(s.[date upgraded]), s.[user]
```

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 now supports the ANSI-SQL Compliant `ROLLUP()` syntax for grouping sets (as opposed to `WITH ROLLUP`) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: Wow, not sure how I managed to miss that ... thanks!  You literally just made my day.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USERNAME,
CONVERT(CHAR(7), DATE_FIELD,120) AS MONTH,
SUM(CASE WHEN UPGRADE = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) UPGRADED
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY USERNAME, CONVERT(CHAR(7), DATE_FIELD,120)
```